# Socket.IO - Message sent from client is failing on server and client

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, electron

I am working on a realtime data communication platform that uses Socket.IO to connect from server to client. The server is running Node.JS, and the client is a desktop application in the form of a webpage using Atom's [Electron](http://electron.atom.io).

I am receiving messages on the client perfectly well, but when I try and send a message, through the format:

```
window.socket.emit('embed',{'...'});
```

The server triggers the error handler:

```
socket.on('error',function(err) {
    console.log('client error: '+JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

I see in my log:

```
client error: {}
```

Debugging Socket.IO on the client side reveals this for the logs when the message is sent:

```
[14184:0511/184052:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "socket.io-client:manager writing packet %j +10s", source: https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js (1)
[14184:0511/184052:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "socket.io-parser encoding packet %j +819ms", source: https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js (1)
[14184:0511/184052:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "socket.io-parser encoded %j as %s +0ms", source: https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js (1)
[14184:0511/184052:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "%cengine.io-client:socket %cflushing %d packets in socket%c +820ms", source: https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js (2)
```

Any clues to why this might be occuring?

**EDIT:**

Both client and server are running Socket.IO version 1.3.5.

Also, attempting to log the error object using console.log results in this line in the console:

```
[TypeError: Property 'undefined' of object #<Object> is not a function]
```

I assume that that function bound to the error event on the server is not designed to accept an error object.

**EDIT:**

Server side, this code is executed to begin the Socket.IO connection.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(1415);

io.on('connection',function(socket) {
    console.log('connection');

    socket.on('error',function(err) {
        console.log('client error: '+JSON.stringify(err));
        console.log(err);
    });

    socket.on('embed',function(obj) {
        var type = obj.type;
        var id = obj.id;
        console.log('--------------------------------------------');
        // ...
        // Additional Application Logic
    });
});
```

Client side, this code is run:

```
window.socket = io('http://localhost:1415');

// When the message is emitted, this code is run. This code is run on a delay, and after messages have been received, so assume a connection is already established
function(id) {
    var type = getType(id);
    window.socket.emit('embed',{id:id,type:type});
}();
```

**EDIT (again):**

Other messages can be sent and received successfully.

Inspecting the raw network data through the web inspector network panel reveals this:

[image: error]

Comment: Do you socket.io versions on client and server match exactly?  I see you're pulling the client socket.io from a CDN rather than pulling it from your server (where versions would match automatically) so you have an opportunity for the versions to not match.

Comment: Also, what do you get if you just do `console.log(err)` on the server side?

Comment: Versions match, and the answer to your other question is edited in the question.

Comment: I think we'll have to see more of the client and server socket code including the setup/connection code on both ends.

Comment: Added the additional code.

Comment: Client-side, are you waiting for the connection to finish before doing the `.emit()`?

Comment: The connection is established, as the client is already receiving messages. The code above is simplified.

Comment: Is it possible that `"embed"` is a reserved message type?  Try changing the message name?  I'm just guessing now.  Did you look at the network trace in the Chrome debugger to see what bits are actually being sent from the client?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Is this as confusing to you as it is to me? I changed it to `embedStart` with no luck.

Comment: You will have to look at the on-the-wire data to see if it is what you expect.  Are you able to send other messages successfully from client to server, just not this one?

Comment: Why is there no data in the object being sent?  Your code shows data in there.  Also, is your code actually `function(id) {`?  Or are you missing a function name in your post?

Comment: No, I removed the function name and added parentheses on the end, it's not really an anonymous function.